# Trying to convert string to int and calculate, but: Unhandled exception type ScriptException

Tags: javascript, java, syntax

We have a string input, let's say `2+2`. Now we want convert it in order to calculate it. I have written the following code for it, it works if I use this `throws ScriptException` in main method. But I don't want use it in my main method. However, I get this exception and I don't know how to get around it?

The problem occurs in line where I have `any(str);`

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Supporter{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "2+2";
            any(str);
    }
    static void any(String hello) throws ScriptException{
         ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
         ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
         System.out.println(engine.eval(hello));
    }
}
```

Comment: you could use a `try...catch` although I don't see anything incorrect with using `throws`.

Comment: That error just means that you haven't specified what should happen if a `ScriptException` gets thrown.  You could write `try{ any(str); } catch (ScriptException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` for example, if you wanted to print out the exception's stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works if I use this throws ScriptException in main method. But I don't want use it in my main method.

Why ? Your code seems perfectly fine to me.

There is no reason to avoid `throws ScriptException` in the main method.

However, if `try..catch` is what you want, try

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "2+2";
    try {
        any(str);
    }catch (ScriptException e) {
       //error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the compiler complains about having an unhandled exception, well... you need to handle it:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "2+2";
    try {
        any(str);
    } catch (ScriptException se) {
        System.out.println("There was a problem evaluating the expression" + str);
    }
}
```